# Laravel 5.1: Validation rule for unique datetime

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a field that is a `datetime` and must be `unique` in the database. In the form, the user will inform a date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. So when I use the validation rule `unique` in the repository for the date field, it is ok because it consider the hour, minute and second. They always will be different.

Do you know if there is any validation rule that ignore the hour, minute and second for a datetime?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try `regex` validation rule? In this case can be the easiest way, like this:

```
'my_date_field' => 'regex:^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$|unique:...'
```